# Ender 3 V2 auto homing

Tags: creality-ender-3

With my Ender 3 V2, to home the extruder, I have to choose **Disable Stepper**, manually move the extruder to the X-axis stop switch; then select **Auto Home**. After that point everything homes correctly.

My question, is there a way to get the extruder to automatically move to the X-axis stop switch and then proceed to auto home after **Auto Home** is selected without selecting **Disable Stepper**?

Comment: Is this at power on or after printing something?

Comment: I would like to be able to do this anytime... I have G-CODE in my Simplify3D code to take the extruder to a neutral location after printing... im not looking for the printer to do anything on its own. I would like to be able to just select Auto Home and have the printer actually auto home without the process of selecting Disable Stepper and moving things manually.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out...
It was a firmware issue. I went to [Creality's Forums](https://forums.creality3dofficial.com/download/ender-series/ender-3-v2/)
and found the appropriate firmware and now it auto homes as I would expect it should.